# Parsing Date/Time in ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to parse a date with ruby so I tried the code below:

```
str = "Mon Jul 02 22:19:00 UTC 2012"
puts DateTime.strptime(str, "%a %b %d H%:M%:S% UTC %Y")
```

But I'm getting this error message:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/date.rb:1576:in `new_by_frags': invalid date (ArgumentError)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/date.rb:1601:in `strptime'
        from get-bid.rb:38
```

When I remove the time from the string and `H%:M%:S%`, parsing works just fine. Did I misuse `strptime`?

Comment: that's it ! Thank you Sorrow :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the parse function?

```
Date.parse("Mon Jul 02 22:19:00 UTC 2012")
```

or

```
Time.parse("Mon Jul 02 22:19:00 UTC 2012")
```

This might free you up from know the exact input format